# Have selection in HTML textarea be visible even if the element is not focused

Tags: html, textarea, selection, html-input

Is it possible to make HTML `textarea` have its selection highlighted even if another element has a focus? I've tried to style the selection using the `::selection` pseudoselector, but this selector is only applied when the element is focused and the selection highlighted. In some UI frameworks, there's a property of visual controls called `HideSelection` which makes the visual control behave as HTML does by default. I'm looking for a way to reverse that.